My Menu bar has got very thin in Sonoma and I can't change it

I've upgraded to Sonoma and since then, my menu bar is too thin for the content - as per the above.  I've tried changing the menu bar size in Accessibility/Display but this had no effect.  I can't find anyone who seems to have had the same problem and whilst it doesn't really matter it's very annoying as I can't see things in the bar properly.  Any ideas?
Thanks!

And if you turn off all those menu bar apps?

I had the same problem and after upgrading to Sequoia 15.0.1 the menu bar returned to its normal size.

Try restarting Finder and the menu bar by running killall Finder and killall SystemUIServer in Terminal. You can also toggle display resolution settings under System Settings > Displays or test in Safe Mode to see if it’s a software glitch. If nothing works, it’s likely a Sonoma bug that’ll need an update.
